# What does the equal sign [=] mean on advanced types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

What does the equal sign mean on this type definition?

`export type Classes<Name extends string | number | symbol = string> = Record<Name, string>`

I'm trying to compile a program that uses this definition but it fails with the following message:

> Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'string'.

I'm using TypeScript 3.5.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `= staing` provides default for generic parameter. Can you reproduce the error in https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html ?

Comment: Assuming you mean the first equals sign, then as @AlekseyL. said, it's a generic parameter default. It means that the generic param given to Classes will default to string if it is not provided. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults

Comment: @AlekseyL. thanks for the explanation! I cannot reproduce the error because it's happening when I import a module, but my question was mostly about TypeScript syntax, really.

Comment: @Collierre thanks for the reference in the docs.